# Error 403 when trying to read from Public Stream

Tags: java, stream

I'm trying to retrieve the data of this stream from Meetup - http://stream.meetup.com/2/open_events

but I keep getting error 403 using the code below

```
URL meetupStream = new URL("http://stream.meetup.com/2/open_events");
BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(meetupStream.openStream()));
String inputLine;
while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null){
      System.out.println(inputLine);
}
in.close();
```

The stream does not need any authentication and can be seen normally in  a browser

Any ideas what could be causing such an error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some webservers complain if your request looks too bleak, may be because they think it was generated by machines? Typically they can tell by the headers you sent. This should already do it:

```
    URLConnection connection = new URL("http://stream.meetup.com/2/open_events").
                                 openConnection();
    connection.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", "Lynx");
    connection.connect();
    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
    connection.getInputStream()));
    String inputLine;
    while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null){
        System.out.println(inputLine);
    }
    in.close();
```

Comment: So is it because I wasn't sending anything as a header?

Comment: Yes, that is very likely. However, another header type might not make it work. To be 100% sure you'd need insight into the server implementation.